# How do I convert an RSS feed's entries into an ebook?

Tags: creation, rss

How would I convert an RSS feed into an ebook?  I know that [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) can already do this but it is a bit bulky and I don't feel confident [writing a recipe in Python](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/news.html) to try to do this.  I do have access to [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) and other tools on Linux, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use <strike>http://newstoebook.com/</strike>¹ I've been using it to create ebooks of one of my project blogs. The resulting ebook (I create .mobi books for Kindles) have been readable. As my blog increased I found it only extracted the most recent posts, so you might want to monitor for this behaviour in case it affects the feeds you want to read as an ebook.

¹ No longer online ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160716103151/http://newstoebook.com:80/)).

Answer (score 5):

If all you're wanting is to easily get specific RSS items to a Kindle, Instapaper has a service that makes this very simple:

http://www.instapaper.com/user/kindle

That's how I do it, and only for specific posts that I'm actually wanting to read on my Kindle. My usual workflow is when I'm reading through my feeds on my iPhone, I click "send to Instapaper" on longer posts that I want to read on my Kindle.

Answer (score 1):

There is a node.js project for this https://github.com/gonejack/rss-epub

Answer (score 0):

you can use ebook-convert from calibre to do this

```
ebook-convert input.recipe output.epub
```

input.recipe come from Calibre Settings\custom_recipes, you can create it by add custom news in Calibre or edit it by your self.